# Does azure conversation transcription service is available in "python"?

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

Problem statement: Need to transcript the speech to text in real-time and distinguish the user
as speaker 1 and speaker 2 using azure cognitive speech service.

Until now I explore the documentation of azure regarding conversation transcription which provides the sample code for Javascript and C#[link for the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-conversation-transcription?pivots=programming-language-javascript)but I was not able to find the sample code in python so does that means azure's this service is not available in python?

Answer (score 0):

> Does azure conversation transcription service is available in "python"?

No, at present **Conversation Transcription SDK** does not support Python language.

**Conversation Transcription SDK** supports only **c#** and **javascript** and is only available in few regions like `centralus`, `eastasia`, `eastus`, `westeurope`.

You can reach Microsoft [here](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport) for support.